# powershell symlink from online location

Tags: powershell, symlink

I have business laptop which I can use off hours for entertainment.
Unfortunately most of my personal folders ale located on the server and that causes some issues.
My 'Documents' folder is located on:

```
\\<server name>\RedirectedFolders$\<username>\Documents
```

Which causes me problems with game that want to use 'My Games' folder located inside 'Documents' folder.
I tried to move 'My Games' to other folder located locally on disk C:, then make symbolic link with PowerShell using command:

```
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "\\<servername>\RedirectedFolders$\<username>\Documents\My Games" -Target "C:\var\games\My Games"
```

Unfortunately it gives error:

```
New-Item: This operation is supported only when you are connected to the server.
```

Does anyone knows how to solve that?

EDIT. Forgot to mention, I'm connected via VPN to my company so when I type in explorer my online link to 'Documents' folder it opens it normally.

Comment: When you're offline, if you run `[Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")` does it still return the path to the server, or do you have offline files enabled in your Folder Redirection GPO (Offline Files is enabled by default)?

Comment: when offline, disconnected from VPN, it still shows path to the server, moreover even when I type in explorer \\<servername> it doesn't give me any error, just opens empty folder.

Answer (score 1):

You reversed the arguments. You want the `-Target` to be the real directory path and the `-Path` to be the local directory link you access the target at. ***You can't create a symbolic link *on* a remote share to a local target.***

Both methods work for me:

```
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Target \\server.domain.tld\share\SomeFolder -Path .\LocalSomeFolder
```

```
cmd /c mklink /D .\SomeLocalFolder \\server.domain.tld\share\SomeFolder
```

---

That said, this won't work like mapped drives and offline files. If you aren't online, you aren't accessing any of those folder's files. You can work around this by mapping the share to a network drive and ensuring offline file access is enabled for the mapping, then symlinking somewhere within the letter drive for the target rather than at the full network path.

This does bring its own share of issues, however, as "Offline Files" for network drives can be finicky.

---

## Workaround

You can work around this gracefully by changing the location of your Documents library to `%USERPROFILE%\Documents`. Note that this won't migrate your existing files so it's up to you to make sure you can obtain the files before or after re-mapping the Documents library and populating your local Documents library with your expected files. Keep in mind some organizations will block changing some or all library locations so this might not be possible for you to achieve on a company-managed workstation.

Also note that this will no longer keep a remote copy of your local Documents library, which might interfere with any backup processes your organization has in place for your workstation. It becomes up to you to keep your Documents backed up in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately I need it in the way I write down in op. The game I want to install put some files on ../Documents/My Games (even when I set installation folder on local path). It "sense" that ../Documents/My Games is on remote share and abort installation. I have similar issues with some install execs when I run them directly from Downloads folder (also located on remote share) but then copying it to anything on c: drive solves the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do what you're asking. I would try enabling "Offline Files" for the network path you want to keep the files local for when you are not connected to the network.

Comment: *Technically* I believe you can create symbolic links if you first map the network drive to a local drive letter, and map the local target under the mapped drive path, however, you have to be an admin to create symbolic links. Elevated processes don't have access to your user drive mappings without some significant hoop-jumping, so if UAC is enabled on your system it's unlikely you'll be able to get this working. I don't recommend disabling UAC for this, and I'm sure your employer would agree if it's already enabled on your system.

Comment: Do you mean "Always available offline" in folder properties, offline files tab? it is ticked and grey out (guess by GPO from domain). Issue is that doesn't matter if I'm online or offline, location in folder properties shows share path. EDIT: I have full admin access to my laptop. Tried with mapped drive gave me that same error as in op. I have access full access to domain controller to (we are very small companies, and I have a lot of rights). Guess I will need to look into GPO.

Comment: It could be greyed out from GPO, you'd have to run `gpresult /h report.html` and inspect the generated report to understand whether that is the case or not. In either regard, what you're asking can't be feasibly done short of a sysadmin creating the symlink for you from the local filesystem of the remote share. I added this to my answer but I would recommend trying to change the location of your `Documents` library if your system allows you to.